# Nextflow rename barcodes and concatenate reads within barcodes

Tags: containers, workflow, pipeline, bioinformatics, nextflow

**My current working directory has the following sub-directories**

[image]

**My Bash script**

[image]

Hi there

I have compiled the above Bash script to do the following tasks:

- rename the sub-directories (barcode01-12) taking information from the metadata.csv
- concatenate the individual reads within a sub-directory and move them up in the $PWD
- then I use these concatenated reads (one per barcode) for my Nextflow script below:

**Query:**

How can I get the above pre-processing tasks (renaming and concatenating) or the Bash script added at the beginning of my following Nextflow script?

[image]

Comment: Hi, please post actual code instead of screenshots of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience, FASTQ files can get quite large. Without knowing too much of the specifics, my recommendation would be to move the concatenation (and renaming) to a separate process. In this way, all of the 'work' can be done inside Nextflow's working directory. Here's a solution that uses the new [DSL 2](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/dsl2.html). It uses the [splitCsv](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#splitcsv) operator to parse the metadata and identify the FASTQ files. The collection can then be passed into our 'concat_reads' process. To handle optionally gzipped files, you could try the following:

```
params.metadata = './metadata.csv'
params.outdir = './results'
```

```
process concat_reads {

    tag { sample_name }

    publishDir "${params.outdir}/concat_reads", mode: 'copy'

    input:
    tuple val(sample_name), path(fastq_files)

    output:
    tuple val(sample_name), path("${sample_name}.${extn}")

    script:
    if( fastq_files.every { it.name.endsWith('.fastq.gz') } )
        extn = 'fastq.gz'
    else if( fastq_files.every { it.name.endsWith('.fastq') } )
        extn = 'fastq'
    else
        error "Concatentation of mixed filetypes is unsupported"

    """
    cat ${fastq_files} > "${sample_name}.${extn}"
    """
}
```

```
process pomoxis {

    tag { sample_name }

    publishDir "${params.outdir}/pomoxis", mode: 'copy'

    cpus 18

    input:
    tuple val(sample_name), path(fastq)

    """
    mini_assemble \\
        -t ${task.cpus} \\
        -i "${fastq}" \\
        -o results \\
        -p "${sample_name}"
    """
}
```

```
workflow {

    fastq_extns = [ '.fastq', '.fastq.gz' ]

    Channel.fromPath( params.metadata )
        | splitCsv()
        | map { dir, sample_name ->

            all_files = file(dir).listFiles()

            fastq_files = all_files.findAll { fn ->
                fastq_extns.find { fn.name.endsWith( it ) }
            }

            tuple( sample_name, fastq_files )
        }
        | concat_reads
        | pomoxis
}
```

Comment: Thanks Steve. Your suggestions worked for me.